# Passing an IF statement with several elif branches using multiple columns to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Here is a snapshot of my dataframe (mrp): https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWRGp.png

I am trying to apply the following logic to each row and save the result into a new column:

```
def planning_period(x):
    if x <= 30:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02']
    elif x <= 60:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02'] + mrp['p03']
    elif x <= 90:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02'] + mrp['p03'] + mrp['p04']
    elif x <= 120:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02'] + mrp['p03'] + mrp['p04'] + mrp['p05']
    elif x <= 150:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02'] + mrp['p03'] + mrp['p04'] + mrp['p05'] + mrp['p06']
    elif x <= 180:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02'] + mrp['p03'] + mrp['p04'] + mrp['p05'] + mrp['p06'] + mrp['p07']
    elif x <= 210:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02'] + mrp['p03'] + mrp['p04'] + mrp['p05'] + mrp['p06'] + mrp['p07'] + mrp['p08']
    elif x <= 240:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02'] + mrp['p03'] + mrp['p04'] + mrp['p05'] + mrp['p06'] + mrp['p07'] + mrp['p08'] + mrp['p09']
    elif x <= 270:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02'] + mrp['p03'] + mrp['p04'] + mrp['p05'] + mrp['p06'] + mrp['p07'] + mrp['p08'] + mrp['p09'] + mrp['p10']
    else:
        return mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02'] + mrp['p03'] + mrp['p04'] + mrp['p05'] + mrp['p06'] + mrp['p07'] + mrp['p08'] + mrp['p09'] + mrp['p10'] + mrp['p11']

mrp['daily_consumption'] = mrp['rem_dys'].apply(planning_period)
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this:

1. if the value of the cell in "rem_dys" column <= 30, then add "p01" + "p02" column values to a new cell in column "daily_consumption"
2. if the value of the cell in "rem_dys" column <= 60, then add "p01" + "p02" + "p03" column value to a new cell in column "daily_consumption"
3. so on and so forth until "rem_dys" column <= 270.
   It's basically a 30 (days) step between each IF statement, representing every month in a year (took an average of 30 day for the sake of simplicity).

However, when i run this Python spits out the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/grumpybear/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
> line 3621, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 136, in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
> "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 163, in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
> "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
> "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError:
> 'daily_consumption'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/grumpybear/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
> line 3799, in _set_item_mgr
> loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)   File "/home/grumpybear/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
> line 3623, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'daily_consumption'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/grumpybear/Projects/python/alw-mrp/mrp-0.12.py", line 352, in
>
> mrp['daily_consumption'] = mrp['rem_dys'].apply(planning_period)   File
> "/home/grumpybear/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
> line 3645, in **setitem**
> self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)   File "/home/grumpybear/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
> line 3788, in _set_item_frame_value
> self._set_item_mgr(key, arraylike)   File "/home/grumpybear/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
> line 3802, in _set_item_mgr
> self._mgr.insert(len(self._info_axis), key, value)   File "/home/grumpybear/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py",
> line 1235, in insert
> raise ValueError( ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (1688, 1688)

I know I'm doing something wrong (this is my first Python code) but don't know what or how to fix it...

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Seems like a complicated way to achieve your goal. Please provide a reproducible example (as **text**) and explain the logic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @quamrana added the full error traceback. sorry, i just didn't want to spam with the whole thing...

Comment: @mozway, I am pretty sure this can be transformed in a much nicer and cleaner code, but it's the best I was able to come up to at this point... Added more info the question. I hope it's OK now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue here is that you return (aggregated) columns instead of values here (e.g. `mrp['p01'] + mrp['p02']` will be a pd.Series with the length of your DataFrame rather than the one value you actually want to have). So you won't be able to assign the returned value of the apply as it is not a list (1D array), but rather a 2D array.

So what you can do is to use the apply for each row and calculate the values per row instead of using the entire columns:

```
def planning_period(row: pd.Series) -> float:
    if row["rem_dys"] <= 30:
        return row['p01'] + row['p02']
    elif row["rem_dys"] <= 60:
        ...

mrp['daily_consumption'] = mrp.apply(lambda row: planning_period(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick, indeed!